# Cast with GetType()

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

Is it possible to cast an object to the type returned from `GetType()`? I'd like a generic method that can accept an object (for anonymous types) but then return an object cast as the anonymous type. I've been thinking of using the LCG DynamicMethod to build a method on a container class, but I can't exactly figure out what that would look like. The idea to cast with the `GetType()` method was to be able to get the anonymous type and cast an object to its actual type without actually knowing the type.

The overarching goal is to stick anonymous-typed objects into a container, that I could then share and pass between methods.

Comment: I'm curious about your use case here, as wouldn't the variable type need to be correct as well, and dynamic typing isn't possible.

Comment: I'm guessing a generic method?

Comment: This one is pretty old. I was originally looking at implementing a Tutorial D language in C# using anonymous types as a storage mechanism. Turned out to be a bad idea. dynamic could change that, but I've since given up on the project ... for now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your intent is very unclear; however, one option is generics and `MakeGenericMethod` in particular. What do you want to do with this? For example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object obj = 123.45;
        typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoSomething")
            .MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType())
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
    }
    public static void DoSomething<T>(T value)
    {
        T item = value; // well... now what?
    }    
}
```

So now we have the value, typed as `double` via generics - but there still isn't much we can do with it except for calling *other* generic methods... what was it you want to do here?

Answer (score 52):

I can't think of why you'd want to cast as GetType(), because you wouldn't be able to do anything to useful with the result, without knowing the type at compile time anyway.

Perhaps what you are looking for, is being able to Convert. If that is the case, the following should work for you:

```
object input = GetSomeInput();
object result = Convert.ChangeType(input, someOtherObject.GetType());
```

We use this when reading values from the registry which are all stored as strings, and then stuffing them into properties using reflection.

Comment: note: the type returned by GetSomeInput() must implement IConvertible (with the top down).  I presume that the intrinsic .NET CLR types all do. ;)

Comment: I changed answers. Though convert is helpful, it returns an object. What I really needed was the actual type returned.

Comment: Here is a valid use case: from a call to a third party library we get a method name, a PropertyInfo and a value that is always a double. Since several methods' parameters are integers our application was crashing. With this code we can convert the received double to the ParameterInfo.ParameterType without any issues. Thank you!  :)

Comment: Use case I'm now using: Base Object type saved in RavenDB, but I need the full type for Razor view engine in ASP.net MVC. Thanks!

Comment: I found `Convert.ChangeType(input, property.PropertyType);` as per this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703723/convert-string-to-type-where-type-is-a-variable

to be what I needed for a similar situation

Comment: A use case: I have SSIS custom component code that needs to be able to run in an environment where one of several versions of the Oracle ODP.NET drivers are installed, either in the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess or Oracle.DataAccess namespace.  They have a common set of Oracle-specific methods, but there is no interface shared between them that covers those methods (D'oh!), and they're sealed.  I want to be able to cast to the run-time type and use it with agnostic code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Activator.CreateInstance` method to create an instance from a type.

FYI reflection is SLOOWWWW, so if you need to do this cast many times in a row, it may be better to define your types in an enum or something like this then create instances without using reflection.

Comment: And how do you create instances from types stored in enum without reflection?

Comment: C# enums don't store types, the specific enum is a type, each instantiation of that enum has a value.  If you want to use an enum to create a type from then you should just use a factory and hard code it to new up your types.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class that I use for change tracking in my [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) app because not all items were [databound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data). Most items were [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) controls, but there were [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) and [DateTimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) controls as well.

For simplicity, my `HasChanged` property tests the generic [Windows.Forms.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) to see if it is a *ComboBox*, but you could test whatever types of controls you add to your Windows Form.

Below is that class - if it helps for anyone.

```
internal class DataItem
{
    private static Color originalBackColor, changedBackColor, originalForeColor, changedForeColor;
    private static Font originalFont, changedFont;

    static DataItem()
    {
        originalBackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        changedBackColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        originalForeColor = Color.Black;
        changedForeColor = Color.Red;
        originalFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.5f);
        changedFont = new Font(originalFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    public static void ChangeSetup(Control original, Color changedBackgroundColor)
    {
        originalBackColor = original.BackColor;
        originalForeColor = original.ForeColor;
        originalFont = original.Font;
        changedBackColor = changedBackgroundColor;
        changedFont = new Font(originalFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    private bool changeTracking;

    public DataItem(Control control, Object value)
    {
        this.Control = control;
        var current = String.Format("{0}", Control.Text).Trim();
        if (Control is ComboBox)
        {
            var cbo = (ComboBox)Control;
            current = cbo.StateGet();
        }
        this.OriginalValue = current;
        this.Control.TextChanged += Control_TextChanged;
        changeTracking = true;
    }

    public Control Control { get; private set; }

    private void Control_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TrackingChanges)
        {
            if (HasChanged)
            {
                this.Control.BackColor = originalBackColor;
                this.Control.Font = originalFont;
                this.Control.ForeColor = originalForeColor;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.BackColor = changedBackColor;
                this.Control.Font = changedFont;
                this.Control.ForeColor = changedForeColor;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            var current = String.Format("{0}", Control.Text).Trim();
            if (Control is ComboBox)
            {
                var cbo = (ComboBox)Control;
                current = cbo.StateGet();
            }
            return !current.Equals(OriginalValue);
        }
    }

    public String OriginalValue { get; private set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        changeTracking = false;
        this.OriginalValue = String.Empty;
        this.Control.Text = String.Empty;
        this.Control.BackColor = originalBackColor;
        this.Control.Font = originalFont;
        this.Control.ForeColor = originalForeColor;
    }
    public bool TrackingChanges
    {
        get
        {
            return changeTracking;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Full Disclosure: There is a `StateGet` extension above that is not included.

Answer (score -3):

You can use getClass() which returns a Class object then use the cast method in the Class object to cast the object to an object of that Class's type, like so:

myObj.getClass().cast(myObj)