# Converting an object of the type Object to another type using a Type object

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Having an object like this:

```
object integerObject=1;
```

And an object like this:

```
Type integerType=typeof(Int32);
```

How can be the *integerType* object used to cast the *integerObject* to the type of *Int32*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int result = (int)Convert.ChangeType(integerObject, integerType);
```

Of course, its a largely useless exercise in this case, but if your "integerObject" was defined differently (a string perhaps) then it is a valid way to do things I guess.

You might be interested in this question too: [Cast with GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555462/cast-with-gettype)

Answer (score 5):

The type of the object that `integerObject` refers to is already `Int32`, albeit the boxed version.

I suspect you have a third line of code which you haven't shown us, which is where you want to actually use the result of the operation you want us to help you with. Unfortunately, without that third line it's hard to know how to help.

The answer *may* involve generics. It *may* be as simple as a call to [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) - but without knowing the bigger picture, we can't really tell I'm afraid.