# Is there anyway to define a single event handler for variety of events in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, delegates, event-handling

I would like to declare common handler for variety of events, that will basically route events to the JavaScript part of the app. I myself come for JS/AS3 background, where something like this is a relatively simple thing to do. SilverLight and C# look quite stricter though.

The plan is like follows, JS will call a special ***[ScriptableMember]*** with a class name to instantiate and method to call, as string arguments. ***[ScriptableMember]*** then must contruct an instance of the class and optionally subscribe to the events, that can be fired by that instance. Events to subscribe to, will be exposed in public static struct of some kind. ***[ScriptableMember]*** will have to extract event properties from that struct and subscribe with the single event handler to all of them. Common single event handler then should translate C# events to JS ones.

Obviously everything should be generalized and automated in some kind of factory logic.

One big problem to this is that I cannot know beforehand what will be the type of delegate or EventArgs object. And even if I knew it would have been troublesome to create an overload for each and every case. Is there anyway to define a generic event handler in C#?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a code snippet that deals with described logic:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public void exec(string compName, string action, ScriptObject scriptObject)
{
    String compFQName;
    Type compClass; 
    object comp;    

    compFQName = "fully.qualified.name." + compName;

    compClass = Type.GetType(compFQName);

    if (compClass != null) {
        comp = Activator.CreateInstance(compClass);

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = compClass.GetField("dispatches", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        object[] dispatches = (object[])fieldInfo.GetValue(comp);

        if (dispatches != null) {
            foreach (string eventName in dispatches) {
                EventInfo eventInfo = compClass.GetEvent(eventName);
                Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, "OnComponentEvent");
                eventInfo.AddEventHandler(comp, handler);
            }                       
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then there is an event handler that should catch up all the events:

```
public void OnComponentEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Could you register an eventhandler for EventArgs and pass subclasses of EventArgs when raising the event?

Comment: Every event args must be inherited from `EventArgs` class. If you follow this rule, you just can declare your handler like `public void GenericHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)` and subscribe it to any event

Comment: @dvvrd you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every event args must be inherited from `EventArgs` class. If you follow this rule, you just can declare your handler like

```
public void GenericHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and subscribe it to any event

**EDIT:**
Like said O. R. Mapper, if the signature of your handler is incomparable with told above, you can call it from anonimous method that subscribed to your event, for example:

```
public delegate void StupidEventHandler(int walueThatMustBeWrappedToEventArgs);
public event StupidEventHandler StupidEventOccured;

//....

{
    //....
    stupidClass.StupidEventOccured += delegate(int value) { handlerObject.GenericHandler(stupidClass, new StupidEventHandlerWrapper(value)); }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Since the question suggests unusial .NET feature usage, handling would be unusual too. Since YOU subscribe this to everything you must know what events types can occure. Then handle it like this:

```
public void GenericHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is MouseEventArgs)
    {
        var mouseArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
        // .. process this case
    }
    else if (e is ....)
}
```

**EDIT:**

To subscribe it try this:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public void exec(string compName, string action, ScriptObject scriptObject)
{
    String compFQName;
    Type compClass; 
    object comp;    

    compFQName = "fully.qualified.name." + compName;

    compClass = Type.GetType(compFQName);

    if (compClass != null) {
        comp = Activator.CreateInstance(compClass);

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = compClass.GetField("dispatches", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        object[] dispatches = (object[])fieldInfo.GetValue(comp);

        if (dispatches != null) {
            foreach (string eventName in dispatches) {
                EventInfo eventInfo = compClass.GetEvent(eventName);

                EventHandler handlerMethod = OnComponentEvent;
                var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handlerMethod.Target, handlerMethod.Method);
                eventInfo.AddEventHandler(comp, handler);
            }                       
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Why your version doesn`t work is a great mistery.

Comment: And, adding to this, where the event argument list is different for some reason, I'd still have one named method and, where necessary, call that from anonymous lambda methods.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, can you provide an example?

Comment: @dvvrd, but won't it result in data loss or something?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I edited an answer with your note, check if I am mistaken

Comment: @jayarjo, What do you mean? You handled your event, do with it what you want

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of :-)

Comment: @dvvrd, I mean type-casting to the parent or grand-parent type. Suppose I'm trying to catch mouse event with it's MouseEventArgs or even MouseButtonEventArgs, will a signature like this: (object sender, EventArgs e) be able catch it as well? Without any loss in event args?

Comment: @jayarjo, the handled EventArgs is the same instance it was produced by the sender. Further you may cast it to required type and use as in the usual handler

Comment: But how do I cast it to required type if I do not know at that moment what it was? :|

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to cast to a type if I know it's name? Like: (Type.GetType('MouseEventArgs'))mouseArgs?

Comment: @jayarjo, actually this is already another question and it was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555462/cast-with-gettype)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to work - callback with this signature (object sender, EventArgs e) is not able to catch MouseEventArgs, throws error :| Problem is resolved as soon as I add an overload with (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) signature. Any ideas?

Comment: @jayarjo, Why? Show your code. It works fine for me and, I can bet, for everyone who used to do it. And from common sence it must work

Comment: I've added a snippet to my question.

Comment: Awesome!.. This one worked. Thanks!.. :) Interesting what was wrong with my version.

Comment: It seems that handler requires explicit cast to EventHandler type. After this it starts to work, no matter how you create it.