# Passing interfaces into RESTFUL API calls

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Recently, I had an interview question where the problem being displayed was passing a parameter as its interface.  Now, I have always been under the impression you must pass concretes because there is no way to know which instantiation to materialize.  Additionally, I was always under the impression you "could" return interfaces...but you should return concretes (as well).

**Q: Is parameterizing interfaces a bad idea?**
**Q: Is returning interfaces "okay"?**
**Q: If more than one exists, how are you going to know which derivation to instantiate?**

**UPDATE - TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR**
Sorry for the clarifications...

**If I send this to the server:** 
 - How will it know which derivation to instantiate? (this should fail...right?)

```
var customer = { Name: 'Frank The Tank',  Orders: [] } 
$.get(url, customer, cb);
```

**Versus, if I send this to the server:** 
 - How will it know which derivation to instantiate?
 - Does the concrete type follow?  (I've never actually checked)

```
var customer = new InsideSalesCustomer('Frank The Tank', []); 
$.get(url, customer, cb);

var customer = new ExternalCustomer('Bilbo Baggins', []); 
$.get(url, customer, cb);
```

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<IOrder> Orders { get; }
}

public interface IOrder
{
    IEnumerable<IOrderItem> OrderItems { get; }
}

public interface IOrderItem
{
    IEnumerable<IProduct> Products { get; }
}

public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    // I was always told Customer & OrderItem should be a concretes
    public IEnumerable<IOrderItem> ListOrderItems(ICustomer customer)
    {
        // Return All OrderItems for all orders
        return customer.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a valid reason to have multiple derivations of `ICustomer` or `IOrder` (possibly specific to a `ICustomer`) then there is nothing wrong with using generic code such that you don't have to have duplication for each concrete type. I always try to have functions that operate on the most abstracted layer as possible to achieve the goal.

Comment: `ApiController` offers (encourages you to use) several implementations of `IHttpActionResult`.  So it's safe to say returning an interface is perfectly fine.  I'm curious what the interviewer said was correct?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO, what do you mean, `how are you going to know which derivation to instantiate`?

Comment: 1) no. 2) returning interfaces is totally fine.  3) You would need a custom model binder or media formatter.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I'm under the impression Web API knows nothing about the underlying concrete object being sent via AJAX.  All it knows is...this conforms to ICustomer.  Sooooo...if there are more than one...how are you going to instantiate the correct derivation of ICustomer?

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree...but lets assume for a moment there is a valid reason (I have no idea what it is).  Remember, this was an interview question.

Comment: Will this even work in Web API (without custom converter code)? https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/web-api-and-interface-parameters/

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this was in Web API. You could pass an additional variable with the specific type you want it to become and then use a factory to instantiate that type.

Comment: Now you guys are getting it...I know you CAN use an interface...but is it correct to do so?  And how would you know what type to instantiate?

Comment: It's just as correct (no more, no less) than using interfaces in any piece of code. I think you are totally missing the point of an interface if your question is "how do you know what type to instantiate?". If you use an interface, the method should not care about the concrete type and should be able to do its thing simply based on ICustomer.

Answer (score 2):

By using interfaces in this scenario you are allowing more code reuse. Any customer that uses the `ICustomer` interface will be able to be passed into this method. In addition, any OrderItem that uses `IOrderItem` will be able to be iterated through. This gives you many more possible uses for this method than using just `USACustomers` and `USOrderItem`, which will lock you into those concrete types. By using interfacses, you can pass any customers and iterate through the returned OrderItem.

To answer your questions

**Q: Is parameterizing interfaces a bad idea?**

No, and it is definitely not a bad idea in your scenario.

**Q: Is returning interfaces "okay"?**

Yes, returning an interface is just returning any type that implements that interface.

**Q: If more than one exists, how are you going to know which derivation to instantiate?**

You can gather the type of the object, it will never return your interface.

```
Type objectType = myObject.GetType();
```

You can then cast the object if you wish. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555462/cast-with-gettype)

```
object result = Convert.ChangeType(input, someOtherObject.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

This, as posted, will actually not work at all in WebAPI, and that might have been the goal of the interview question.

Why? The WebAPI model binder will not be able to figure out the runtime type of the given `ICustomer`, and thus when you actually enter into the method, you'll see that the ICustomer object is simply null since it was skipped during binding.

I just tried it myself with an ultra-simple example. If I use `ICustomer` as my parameter type, it always comes in null.
If I use a `Customer`, everything works fine.

You *are* able to use interfaces as parameters by using custom model binders, by the way, it just doesn't work directly "out of the box". There's plenty of material on how to do that, I won't get into it here.